# Configuring multiple rabbitmq in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I will be receiving a message from rabbitmq A and after processing, I need to send data to another rabbitmq (external). So far I have seen example with single rabbitmq configuration with spring-boot. I couldn't find config in [properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#common-application-properties). How multiple rabbitmq can be configured in spring-boot? It is unusual, but there is a need to receive message from one mq and push different data to another mq.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        jobs:
          destination: jobs
          group: test
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
```

Comment: Usually when you need "more than one" of a particular thing in Spring Boot, you have to configure through the Java code and not from the yaml configuration. Because probably qualifiers will become involved to be able to isolate which bean maps to which RabbitMQ instance. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41344691/424903

Comment: Thanks. How I can link this to Sink & Source i.e Spring integration without using RabbitTemplate.