# Connecting to different RabbitMQ instances using SpringBoot and Camel RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-camel

From my spring-boot service(with camel) I need to connect to two RabbitMQ instances;not cluster, but altogether different instances(with diff IP, vhost and credentials)

**Versions**: **spring-boot**: 1.5.12 and **camel**: 2.21.5

I want to create multiple connection factories and specify them in the camel endpoint name like this.
`rabbitmq:exchange1?connectionFactory=#customFactory1`
`rabbitmq:exchange2?connectionFactory=#customFactory2`

Currently this is not supported as **RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration** class expects only one instance of ConnectionFactory

Even if I qualify the ConnectionFactory Beans with `@Qualifier`/`@Primary` the connectionFactory query param used in camel endpoint is ignored (or) properties from `camel.component.rabbitmq` are taking priority

I'm now using a workaround to specify all the connection properties in the endpoint name like
`rabbitmq:exchange1?host=<host>&vhost=<vhost>&username=something&password=something`

Is there a better way to achieve this...?

Comment: check this out .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520784/rabbitmq-rpc-across-multiple-rabbitmq-instances

Comment: These customFactory1 and customFactory2, Are they autowired instances?

Comment: @SunandPadmanabhan Yes, they are, Camel expects connectionFactory as spring bean

Comment: @LalitMehra I've seen that already, but that solution works well with spring-amqp and RabbitTemplate, but in my case I'll just specify the endpoint name, camel(camel-rabbitmq-starter is the library) chooses the connectionFactory, so when I tried, it couldn't resolve the conflict btw two connFactories